# Google Page Speed Insights API: Internet Error

Tags: optimization, google-api, google-cloud-platform, google-pagespeed

I am getting an error from Google PageSpeed Insights API. Its just returns Internal Error with Code 500. 
Here is the detailed response:

```
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "internalError",
    "message": "An error occurred while fetching or analyzing the page."
   }
  ],
  "code": 500,
  "message": "An error occurred while fetching or analyzing the page."
 }
}
```

I also Tried with Google API key from within Google Cloud Console (Enabled
   PageInsights APi for my account). No Luck still the same message.

Here is a result screenshot of the same page tested on tools.pingdom.com
[image]

[image]

It would be helpful if Google Provided detailed error messages which can help us identify where the issue is. Any help or pointers on this would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with an SVG image. Once it was removed Page Speed starting working. Still not sure what was wrong with the image.

Answer (score 0):

You have too many resources loading on page load. The Render limit is 200. 
You can also try to test your site with [think with Google](https://testmysite.thinkwithgoogle.com/)