# Google PageSpeed Insights Error: An error occurred while fetching or analyzing the page

Tags: pagespeed

Does anyone know how to get any information on what causes this issue or how to go about debugging it?   Site is wreathsunlimited.com

Google PageSpeed Insights at developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights runs to about 70% and then terminates with "An error occurred while fetching or analyzing the page."  The site runs clean with: [webpagetest.org](http://www.webpagetest.org), [pingdom.com](https://www.pingdom.com/), [dotcom-tools.com](https://www.dotcom-tools.com/), [gtmetrix.com](https://gtmetrix.com/) and [Bing's tool](https://bing.com/webmaster/tools/mobile-friendliness) .  It fails every time with Google's PageSpeed Insights.  Also, Google Analytics reports no page timings.

The site is a WordPress / WooCommerce site and uses CloudFlare (Pro account) as the CDN and uses WP Super Cache or W3 Total Cache to cache the WordPress pages.  Both CloudFlare and WP Super Cache / W3 Total Cache have been removed to eliminate possible issues.

We also tried using the Google pagespeed api.  It returns the 500 response below.  We have removed CloudFlare so the 500 error has to be from Google's server or the site being tested  (wreathsunlimited.com).  Does anyone know which?  We can find no 500 errors in the server logs, but I think it is possible that some 500 errors don't get logged (I could be wrong).

```
curl "https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v1/runPagespeed?url=https://www.wreathsunlimited.com/&key=(apikey)"
{
"error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "internalError",
    "message": "An error occurred while fetching or analyzing the page."
   }
  ],
  "code": 500,
  "message": "An error occurred while fetching or analyzing the page."
}
}
```

Since Google uses page speed to weight search results, we are concerned that SEO is suffering because the site will not run PageSpeed Insights.

Any help or idea's will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem with the api and the web service. We found out that the pages peed score tool has a limit of 200 assets that can be loaded. We ran into that problem because there where a lot of images, js files and ads.

Sources:

- https://moz.com/community/q/google-pagespeed-insights-error
- [Google Page Speed Insights API: Internet Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43261400/google-page-speed-insights-api-internet-error)

Answer (score 0):

We did finally find the answer to why we kept getting "An error occurred while fetching or analyzing the page." whenever we tried Google Page Speed Insights  Not sure it will apply to anyone else, but I thought I would post the cause and solution we used.

It had to with a SVG image in the header.  If it is coded like either of these 2 methods, Google PageSpeed Insights fails:

```
<img src="header.svg" >
```

or

```
<svg >
<style type="text/css">
@font-face{font-family:'Apple-Chancery';src:url("data:;base64,...");}
</style>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 119.7441 96.1353)" fill="#005A35" font-family="'Apple-Chancery'" font-size="72">Text</text>
</svg>
```

We solved it by using the  directive inside the  tags like:

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="260" height="44.1168289291" viewBox="0 0 719.744 122.651" enable-background="new 0 0 719.744 122.651" xml:space="preserve">
<title>Wreaths Unlimited</title>
<desc>Wreaths Unlimited Home</desc>
<image x="0px" y="0px" width="100%" height="100%" xlink:href="/slider-images/wu-logo-1-09-02b-2017.svgz"></image>
</svg>
```

Coding the svg image this way lets all pages complete PageSpeed Insights.

Regards,
Don

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue with two shopify websites. I removed the SVG's with .pngs and it did not fix the issue.

Upon further investigation I found that one of the apps was the issue. Specifically, Privy - Free email popups with exit intent.

If you're experiencing something similar I would recommend disabling/deleting plugins one at a time until you find a culprit.

Hope this helps someone banging their head against a wall.