# I don't know how to solve page speed error

Tags: pagespeed, google-pagespeed

I got this error message from google page speed test ... "Backend error" and that's all. Can anyone help me to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google PageSpeed Insights Error: An error occurred while fetching or analyzing the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43643267/google-pagespeed-insights-error-an-error-occurred-while-fetching-or-analyzing-t)

Answer (score 0):

Possible reason is that Pagespeed tries to parse the page within a certain time and if does not happen it gives different error such as the one you mentioned i.e. "Backend error".

The solution is to see if indeed your website is slow(many of the time database intensive plugins/ codes are to be blamed) and after resolving that you might able to see the result in pagespeed.